# Any Windows client available for HTTP live streaming

Tags: windows, http

Is there any Windows client available for HTTP live streaming?
Will Safari work on Windows platform or only on OS X?

Comment: One more doubt : Will QuickTime Player X works on Windows for HTTP Live Streaming or that also require Mac Laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Safari works well in Windows, also QuickTime.

Comment: it just shows me the playlist without playing any movies. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

VLC should do it - it does HTTP streaming, and just about anything but walk your dog. It even acts as a [source](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html) for http streaming

Answer (score 0):

[3ivx](http://www.3ivx.com/technology/windows/metro/http_live_streaming.html) technologies has a windows 8 and windows phone http live streaming client sdk for app developers to add HLS support to their xaml or HTML 5 apps.

I believe they're working on a standalone player too